# javafx2 center axes on XYChart

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

JavaFX does not provide a CENTER value for Side so I am trying to center the X and Y Axis by translation:

scanXAxis.setTranslateY(0.5*scanYAxis.getBoundsInParent().getHeight());     // xAxis initially on TOP

scanYAxis.setTranslateX(0.5*scanXAxis.getBoundsInParent().getWidth());      // yAxis initially on LEFT

The result I am getting however are axes crossing at a point that depends on the scene's size instead of (0,0) i.e I can get them crossed at the origin by manually resizing the scene. This is exaclty the reverse of what I am striving for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Axis and I think the design is not friendly. I can't set the axis upside down or right to the left. I used axis.rotate but I have to hack the code for the layout of the contentPlot. Also, the axis can only be set to the left, right, top or bottom. But I want some flexibility, e.g. when I implement parallel coordinates, I can't put it to the place I really want to put it. So I am thinking I have to write my own axis class instead.